# Relabel configs in Prometheus alert manager

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have alert rules in Prometheus and I want to achieve that I don't see the cluster label in the alert but instead I see the env label. I tried to use this code but absolutely no result.

```
- alert: SQL
      expr: avg(rate(pg_stat_database_blks_hit{datname!~"template.*", cluster="prod"}[5m]) / (rate(pg_stat_database_blks_hit{datname!~"template.*", cluster="prod"}[5m]) + rate(pg_stat_database_blks_read{datname!~"template.*", cluster="prod"}[5m]))) by (datname, cluster) < 0.98
      for: 2m
      labels:
        severity: email
        env: "{{ $labels.env }}"
      annotations:
        summary: "PostgreSQL low cache "
        description: "PostgreSQL low on cache ..."
      relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [cluster]
          action: drop
        - source_labels: [cluster]
          target_label: env
```

Can anyone advise me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If prometheus is the source for your alerts, you might use `alert_relabel_configs`. If that's not the case, although not very clean, *label_replace* on expression would do the work.